# Coating for whiteboard

Tags: paint, materials

I want to make a whiteboard using [hardboard](https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/comments/493kyb/iceland_in_8k/). I understand it works pretty well, but if you leave marker on it for a while, it could become hard to erase.

I'm hoping therefore to try an experiment where I coat some small sections of hardboard with various coatings, draw on each section, then see which one erases best after a week.

What are some coatings I should try for each test section of board? Furniture lacquer? Nail polish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clear 2 part urethane would be your best bet.  lacquers, latexes and even epoxies are all susceptible to dissolution by many different solvents.  i don't think the dry erase marker uses anything too strong, but binary urethanes are almost chemically inert once cured.  there are very few solvents that will dissolve them - highly unlikely they are in dry erase markers.

keshlam's suggestion of glass would really be ideal.  just backpaint it white if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer. I'd like to be able to apply my coat evenly, of course, so I'm thinking a spray would be most effective. I haven't been able to find any two-part urethane sprays. Would you expect the single-part sprays to be sufficient?

Comment: just get  a cheap air spray gun from harbourfreight or some such place and shoot it on.  the single part urethanes are nowhere near the same chemical resistivity.

Comment: Ok I think I did find one. How does this look? [Eastwood 2K AeroSpray Matte Clear](https://goo.gl/C4zYiU)

Comment: thats actually really cool.  i have never seen a binary spray can before.  i would use gloss, not matte.  however, either way, let  me know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For home use, I generally scribble on glass -- usually my bathroom mirror.